# Ionic splash screen size

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have added a splash screen to my Ionic App. 
I have followed the official Ionic Framework procedure.

Everithing work but the splash screen on [device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO93S.jpg) is not like the [real image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6yHF.jpg) because the circle in the center is became an oval.

Could anyone say me something more about this problem or give me a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run the command: "ionic resources --splash" ? This will generate the splash image for all the devices.

Comment: Yes @JosephOcasio , I do. I have followed the [official Ionic Framework procedure](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) to create my splash screen. In some devices it works well but in others it gives me this strange problem.